# How to parse json data then save it as a variable in sql server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Will i am sql server to create json which i import using ASP.NET

My select function:

```
SELECT Sales.SalesID,InvoiceNum,FORMAT(InvoiceDate, 'dd-MMM-yy') AS InvoiceDate,ProductName,Qty,Price 
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN (SalesDetails 
    INNER JOIN Products 
        ON Products.ProductID = SalesDetails.ProductID) 
    ON Sales.SalesID = SalesDetails.SalesID 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

My JSON Output:

```
{
   "SalesID":1,
   "InvoiceNum":"111",
   "InvoiceDate":"11-Feb-19",
   "Products":[
      {
         "ProductName":"Name",
         "SalesDetails":[
            {
               "Qty":5,
               "Price":100
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ProductName":"Name",
         "SalesDetails":[
            {
               "Qty":10,
               "Price":210.00
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My Desired Output:

```
{
   "SalesID":1,
   "InvoiceNum":"11",
   "InvoiceDate":"11-Feb-19",
   "Products":[
      {
         "ProductName":"Name",
         "Qty":5,
         "Price":100
      },
      {
         "ProductName":"Name",
         "Qty":10,
         "Price":210
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to save this as a table with OpenJson After outputing this

My details query is:

[image: Details Query]

My attempt with JSON PATH:
Select:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = (SELECT Sales.SalesID,InvoiceNum,FORMAT(InvoiceDate, 'dd-MMM-yy') AS InvoiceDate,ProductName AS "Products.Name",Qty AS "Products.Qty",Price AS "Products.Price"
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN (SalesDetails 
    INNER JOIN Products 
        ON Products.ProductID = SalesDetails.ProductID) 
    ON Sales.SalesID = SalesDetails.SalesID 
FOR JSON PATH

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (
    SalesID INT 'strict $.SalesID',
    InvoiceNum NVARCHAR(50) '$.InvoiceNum',
    InvoiceDate NVARCHAR(9) '$.InvoiceDate',  
    Products NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Products' AS JSON
  )
```

My output:

[image: JSON Path Query]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I highly suggest making *good* use of line breaks and whitespace when writing; that code is very difficult to read.

Comment: Use `for json path` and aliases to control the json output. [Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#option-1---you-control-output-with-for-json-path)

Comment: The problem with json path is that i have multipule records for each sale to acount for each product so i cant combine the records to a single object

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to provide [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) it would make make it much easier to help you.

Comment: How to write a good SQL question?
There are five ingredients to this recipe:

Provide a clear textual explanation of the problem at hand.
Provide proper sample data, as DDL (create table statement(s)) and DML (insert statement(s)). The sample data should be enough to demonstrate the problem, including edge cases. Usually, a few relevant rows are enough.
Provide expected output for the sample data you've posted.
....

**Do not include images of data or code!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to generate the expected output using `FOR JSON PATH`. With `FOR JSON AUTO`, the format of the JSON output is automatically determined based on the order of columns in the `SELECT` list and their source tables and this format can't be changed.

It's difficult without test data, but the following statement is a possible solution to your problem:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max);
SELECT @json = (
   SELECT 
      s.SalesID, 
      s.InvoiceNum,
      FORMAT(s.InvoiceDate, 'dd-MMM-yy') AS InvoiceDate,
      c.Products
   FROM Sales s
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT p.ProductName, sd.Qty, sd.Price
      FROM SalesDetails sd
      INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = sd.ProductID 
      WHERE sd.SalesID = s.SalesID
      FOR JSON PATH
   ) c (Products)
   FOR JSON PATH    
)
```

After that you may try to parse the generated JSON:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   SalesID INT 'strict $.SalesID',
   InvoiceNum NVARCHAR(50) '$.InvoiceNum',
   InvoiceDate NVARCHAR(9) '$.InvoiceDate',  
   Products NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Products' AS JSON
)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.If i can understand what you are doing is group the values in the products and casting them as an object then adding them as the field is that correct?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTamer Yes, you have three tables, so `FOR JSON AUTO` generates a nested JSON output based on the structure of the SELECT statement. But generating a nested JSON content for `sales details` / `products` of each sale and using `FOR JSON PATH` is an option here (you may see the nested JSON if you remove the last `FOR JSON PATH`).